# Como fazer um JSON com um array de objetos

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho um formulário que é enviado via POST como JSON. Mas tenho um array de objeto chamado aulas[] no JavaScript. O Objeto contem discilpina, ch e curso. Ou seja, o array que é gerado dinamicamente fica algo tipo:

**aulas[{"disciplina":"1","curso":"1","ch":"1"},{"disciplina":"2","curso":"2","ch":"2"}]**

Eu usei serialize() para gerar o JSON do form, mas como faço para passar esse array nesse mesmo JSON de forma que consiga acessar os dados, no php, da mesma forma que acesso com o resultado do serialize().

Tentei usar stringify, mas não tem uma referencia como os outros campos do form.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:  $('#form').serialize()+JSON.stringify(aulas),
    url: "includes/post.php",
    success: function(msg){
        //teste
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) do jQuery para transformar os valores do formulário em json. O problema é que essa serialização geralmente retorna objetos parecidos com `{ 'name' : 'nome', 'value' : 'João' }` e para que o lado servidor consiga tratar essas informações como um objeto, nós utilizamos `$.each` para percorrer os valores do formulário e criar um "array associativo", ou no caso, um objeto json:

```
// constrói o 'array associativo', criando um objeto e atribuindo à ele os parâmetros e valores
var formulario = {};
$.each($("#form").serializeArray(), function() {
    formulario[this.name] = this.value;
});

// envia as informações para o servidor
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "formulario" : formulario,
        "aulas" : aulas
    },
    url: "includes/post.php",
    success: function(msg){
        //teste
    }
});
```

Para você recuperar esses dois valores no php, você terá que utilizar algo como:

```
$formulario = $_POST["formulario"];

// acessando os valores do formulário
echo $formulario["nome_do_campo_do_formulario"];
echo $formulario["outro_do_campo_do_formulario"];

$aulas = $_POST["aulas"];

// acessando os valores do array de aulas
foreach($aulas as $aula) {
    echo $aula["disciplina"] . ", ";
}
```

Comment: Mas como eu faço pra pegar esses dados no php dessa forma? Se eu passo o form eu consigo pegar com $_POST["campoDoForm"]. Dessa forma ele gera só a referencia do formulario e aulas. Como eu  teria que fazer pra pegar só determinado campo dentro do form que passei?

Comment: Fiz alterações na resposta. Veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Isso msmo bro. Me ajudou pacas. Valeu :D